# Flutter how to handle time based events?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am having a widget in the flutter which can be dismissed by watching a rewarded video. But I don't want the widget to be completely dismissed. Say for 3 days.

So if the user clicks on the specific widget then the ads will be disabled for 3 days. Is it possible to do? Could someone help me with references or ideas to get this done?

Please help

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want to achieve but if I do, you should save this date in some kind of database/storage and then every time you build your widget, check if this date is less than 3 days ago.

Comment: Also, if the time delta would be some shorter period of time, you should probably introduce automatic refresh, which checks if this time is gone, but 3 days is pretty long so probably checking every widget rebuild is enough.

Comment: @SzymonKowaliński Thank you. 3 days is long. I will save the date to local storage than will add 3 days. And do a check in the init state. Thanks again for the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Get shared preferences Package to make local storage to track the Date `shared_preferences: ^2.0.5`

Make A Local Storage like this -

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class SetUserLocalStorage {
  Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  void date(String valueOfDate) async {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;
    prefs.setString(UserStorageKey().valueOfDate, valueOfDate);
  }

  void clear() async { // For Your Further Operation, If needed
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;
    prefs.clear();
  }
}

class GetUserLocalStorage {
  Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    Future<String> date() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;
    return prefs.getString(UserStorageKey().valueOfDate);
  }
}

class UserStorageKey {
  String get valueOfDate => "valueOfDate";
}
```

Now, in your page / Screen, Define Variable -

```
  bool _showTheAd = false;
  DateTime _now = DateTime.now();
  DateTime _date = DateTime.now();
```

and In InitState, Start Checking the Condition on the base of Time,I am making it in three part for better understanding

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initialPoint();
  }
```

in `_initialPoint()` -

```
void _initialPoint() async {
    await GetUserLocalStorage().date().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        _date = DateTime.parse(value);
      });
    }).then((value) {
      _conditionCheck();
    });
  }
```

In `_conditionCheck -`

```
  void _conditionCheck() {
    if (_date == null) {
      setState(() {
        _showTheAd = true;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _now = DateTime.now();
      });
      if (_now.isAfter(_date)) {
        setState(() {
          _showTheAd = true;
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

I know that,these are like "dirty code", but I think that will help you understand the scenario.
in body, show the add based on the _showTheAd condition, and use some interceptor / listener of kind to sense when the video is end,I am using an inkwell, and execute the code in `onTap()`, full scenario -

```
Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            if (_showTheAd)
              InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(
                    () {
                      _date = _now.add(
                        Duration(seconds: 5),
                      ); // to add Date _now.add(Duration(days:3));
                    },
                  );
                  SetUserLocalStorage().date(_date.toIso8601String());
                },
                child: Center(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 120,
                    width: 120,
                    color: Colors.red,
                    child: Text("the ad"),
                  ),
                ),
              )
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Can this initState output passed to a provider so that I can use it anywhere?

Comment: Actually this won't work because the initstate cannot have async : State.initState() must be a void method without an `async` keyword.

Comment: right now, I am not able to answer about provider for lacking of "proper knowledge" ,sorry there :(

Comment: Solution that worked for me is a FutureBuilder